# Gitlab Testing suddenly get error with Symfony project

Tags: gitlab, phpunit, gitlab-ci, symfony4

suddenly we have a weird error in the Testing of Gitlab and we don't know what happens, Error is:

assert(): assert($type instanceof Identifier || $type instanceof Name || $type instanceof ComplexType) failed

[image: Error for Gitlab testing for Symfony project]

Can anyone help?

Comment: We've had the same and could not reproduce this locally. This assertions seems to be in phpunit/php-code-coverage. A few days ago with phpunit/php-code-coverage:9.2.7 it worked. We went away from installing phpunit via the symfony bridge and solved it with it. While this might not be a solution for you, maybe this helps pinpointing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but I don't why this happened to me
I just change the PHPUnit version from 9.5 to 8.5 and it fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by updating nikic/php-parser (v4.11.0 => v4.13.0)

php-code-coverage 9.2.8 brings new Node types https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/commit/12856cc6e3827ed187c588fff59baa011bab328d which were handled since php-parser v4.13.0

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue here with `php-code-coverage (9.2.17)` and `nikic/php-parser (v4.15.1)`

is there a way to downgrade `php-code-coverage`